# update row on supabase with Sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I'm trying to update some data in differents row but, for some reason its not working.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import supabase from '../../lib/db';

    let id = $page.params.id;
    let title, content, description;

    const updatePost = async (title, description, content) => {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('posts')
            .update({ title, description, content })
            .eq('id', id);

        return { data, error };
    };

</script>

<form action="" on:submit|preventDefault={updatePost}>
    <input type="text" bind:value={title} />
    <input type="text" bind:value={description} />
    <input type="text" bind:value={content} />
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

I don't have any error but its not updating. I just want to understand why. Everything else is working (create, delete, get).

Comment: Did you look into the network tab, what kind of response comes back from supabase? 4XX error (maybe the error provides information)? Your code looks alright overall imo. My best guess would be that a columns might have a different name than 'title', 'description' or 'content'.
I have not much experience myself. What happens with data and error after the return?

Comment: Hi, there is no error with the code like this. I think the columns name its not the problem, because it works to create posts and/or fetch posts. If I change something I get a error 4xx but with the code like this I don't have any error in return. I think the problem is in the filter `.eq('id', id)` but I have already tried to do diferents filters and nothing works. I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem. There is no parameters to pass. I was overriding the function.

the correct way.

```
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import supabase from '../../lib/db';

    let id = $page.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    let title, content, description;

    const updatePost = async () => {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('posts')
            .update({ title, description, content, updated_at: new Date() })
            .eq('id', id);

        return { data, error };
    };
</script>

<form action="" on:submit|preventDefault={updatePost}>
    <input type="text" bind:value={title} />
    <input type="text" bind:value={description} />
    <input type="text" bind:value={content} />
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```